# How to detect Action bar "Sub-Title" click event in Android Fragment..?

Tags: android

In my Android app I want to detect action bar "Sub-Title" click event but I don't know how to do it. I have successfully done Action bar "Title" click as shown in following code---

```
// Get action bar title ID 
final int abTitleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");    

//Set OnClick event on action bar title
getActivity().findViewById(abTitleId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
       // Done      
    }
});
```

Referring above code, I have tried to detect action bar "Sub-Title" click event as follows, but there is something wrong and I'm getting "Sub-Title Id" null and it is throwing Null-Pointer Exception.

```
            //Set OnClick event on action bar sub-title
final int abSubTitleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_sub_title", "id", "android");
            getActivity().findViewById(abSubTitleId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {

                }
            });
```

Hope you understand. Thanks..!

Comment: are you using custom view for action bar ?

Comment: @Murtaza Hussain Yes, I'm  using custom view for action bar.

Comment: show your xml and initialization code

Answer (score 0):

The best to handle this scenario is to use custom actionbar view, So create a simple actionbar layout with title textview and subtitle textview and implement respective listener. :)

```
    final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);

// Set up your ActionBar
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

// You customization
final int actionBarColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(actionBarColor));

final TextView actionBarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
final TextView actionBarSubTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_sub_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Action Bar subtitle is non clickable as far as i know. Instead you can add the icon there and make it clickable. You can get the click event of icon in `onOptionsItemSelected()`.